# json responses and assigning a name prior to decode

Tags: php, json, curl

Good Afternoon.
 I am successfully uploading property data to the Rightmove test site using json to create $data (see below) and curl to transfer it. This is the curl script which works perfectly well and results in the expected success message form Rightmove..see below....

```
$url = 'abc,com/def.php';           
$ch = curl_init();                              
$cert = "xyz.pem";
if (!stat($cert))
{
 die('No cert');
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $cert);                              
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, 'hidden');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 5); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);


if($result = curl_exec($ch) === false) 
{
   die('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
```

However we need to be able to read the json success message (response) we are getting back (see example below) into a php script for further scripting our end. We know we can use decode to do that. So that isnt the question. Read on....

Here is an example of the json string success message we are getting back from Rightmove - all exactly as expected.

```
{

     "message": "Your property has successfully been uploaded to Rightmove",
     "success": true,
     "errors": null,
     "warnings": [],
     "request_timestamp": "02-08-2016 13:07:50",
     "response_timestamp": "02-08-2016 13:07:50",
     "request_id": "231301-160802-130750-10990",
     "property": {
      "agent_ref": "agent950",
      "rightmove_id": 123456789,
      "change_type": "UPDATE",
      "rightmove_url": "http://www.adftest.rightmove.com/property-to-rent/property-123456789.html"
     }
    }
```

What we need to test now is how to incorporate the above json response data into our php scripts starting  with the json decode snippet below...

```
$var = json_decode($xxx, true);//outputs and associative array 

print_r($var);//prints the array
```

Once we have the $var object back we can then use the data inside it in our scripts.

**The Question**
.....literally all we need to know is what is $xxx (ie what is the name of the json string success message response so we can add it to the decode snippet above and be on our way. Or how do we set $xxx. Rightmove couldnt help.

I suspect we are maybe missing the obvious here and I am going to cringe when you tell me the answer.

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: i dont understand the matter: Why not use the variable $response?

Comment: Isn't it in `$var['message']`?  Is that the "success message" you're looking for?

Comment: If the JSON response is not in the $result variable set the cURL RETURNTRANSFER option and $result should have what is returned so you may process it further. What is the contents of $result now? I would expect the $xxx you are looking for to be $result

Comment: ... Or are you looking for the value you pass to `json_decode()`?  In that case, you've assigned it to `$result`....

Comment: Thank Dave and EatPeanutButter. Before posting this query I had the code  $var = json_decode($result, true); But when I do print_($var) I dont get the expected php array (I get nothing at all)---even though i am getting the expected curl response in json from Rightmove (as shown the original request for help). So there must be something else going on here. I tried Dave's suggestion below ie uncommenting curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1). That caused the Rightmove json response message to NOT be returned at all. Really struggling now!

Comment: your question is unclear. according to your question, you're able to do each required part successfully, so where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: Dave--->you were right. But there was an additional silly error in my code. If you take a look at it $result was never set to curl_excec(ch) which when fixed  together with uncommenting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1) fixed everything. Happy and thank you so much.

Comment: And thank you too meager. You pointed out my silly error per my comment above. Thank you,